# Post-Build event Visual Studio 2015 | Running 2 programs, waiting for one to end and killing the other

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2015, post-build-event

I'm having an issue creating a custom post-build script. It will go something like this.

Solution: 2 Programs (Program A, Program B)
The build order is set to be Program A and then Program B

Program A runs and never ends 
Program B runs and ends
Program A needs to be shut down

PostBuild Event for ProgramA: @ProgramA.exe (Just freezes and never finishes building since ProgramA never ends on it's own)

To clarify my question further, in a linux shell format it would be like this.

```
./ProgramA &
progAPID=$!
./ProgramB &
progBPID=$!
wait $progBPID
kill -KILL $progAPID
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For anyone who ever stumbles upon this, here's how I managed to solve my issue.

```
@echo off
echo "Running Example Batch"
cd %~dp0/../Example
start /min cmd /c ProgramA.exe
ProgramB.exe
taskkill /f /im ProgramA.exe
```